# Cannot 'GET' mLab Data b/c of CORS

Tags: javascript, jquery, mlab

I can't execute the 'GET' request with the getTasks() function.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    getTasks();
});

const apiKey = 'xxxxxxx';

function getTasks(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'https://api.mlab.com/api/1/databases/taskmanager/collections/tasks?apiKey='+apiKey,
        contentType: 'application/json',
        xhrFields: {
            withCredentials: true
        },
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(){
            console.log('FAIL')
        }
    })
}
```

The error that I get is:

> api.mlab.com/api/1/databases/taskmanager/collections/tasks?apiKey=xxxxxxx
>   Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400
>   (Bad Request)​
>
> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. The response
>   had HTTP status code 400.

I understand that Google-Chrome on Windows is CORS enabled, and will not (by default) allow communication with a different domain.  I'm not sure what a preflight request is. Regardless, I tried to implement what I saw from Using [CORS - HTML5 Rocks​](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/#toc-cors-from-jquery) (from the CORS from jQuery section), but to no avail.

Comment: the server needs to send appropriate CORS headers to allow you to *borrow* their resources

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CORS is there to protect you. If you want some more info on it, [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) has a good entry on it.

It appears the issue here is that you're trying to access your mongodb hosted by mlab directly from your web app. As you can see in your code, you're providing credentials/api keys to make that request.

My guess is that mlab's intent of not allowing CORS is to prevent you from doing this. You should *never* put your private API keys in html to be hosted on a web page, as it's easily accessible by reading source code. Then someone would have direct access to your mongodb.

Instead, you should create a server-side application (node, or... ** Whatever **) that exposes an api you control on the same domain (or a domain you give permission to via CORS).

---

As far as the "preflight" request, if you look in your chrome debugging tools, you should see an additional request go out with the "OPTIONS" method. This is the request that chrome (and most other http clients) send out first to a server hosted on a different domain. it's looking for the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header to find out whether it's allowed to make the request. Pretty interesting stuff if you ever have some time to dig into it.

Comment: Looking at their [docs](http://docs.mlab.com/data-api/#i-cannot-update-a-document-using-the-mlab-api-from-an-angularjs-application), it looks like they do support CORS (otherwise that example code wouldn't work at all)

Comment: > The first method - the one we strongly recommend - is to connect using one of the available MongoDB drivers. You do not need to use our API if you use the driver. In fact, using a driver provides better performance, better security, and more functionality.

> The second method, documented in this article, is to connect via mLab’s RESTful Data API. Use this method only if you cannot connect using a MongoDB driver.

Comment: I'm not saying that a server-side solution isn't the better option, just that it appears they do have CORS configured on their REST API

Answer (score 2):

At a guess, the remote API simply does not respond to pre-flight requests for `GET` calls (because it shouldn't have to).

Your code is triggering a pre-flight request because it is [non-simple](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Simple_requests). This is due to your adding a `Content-type: application/json` header. A request `Content-type` header is used to indicate the request payload format. As it is a `GET`, there is no payload.

Try this instead...

```
$.getJSON('https://api.mlab.com/api/1/databases/taskmanager/collections/tasks', {
  apiKey: apiKey
}).done(function(data) {
  console.log(data)
}).fail(function() {
  console.log('FAIL')
})
```

Comment: @masshakar for example, the data in a POST request. The `Content-type` request header informs the server of what format to expect the data to be in. For example, `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, `application/json`, etc

Comment: @masshakar since a `GET` request does not send any data, there is no reason to set a `Content-type` header